# How to visually select lines based on a search pattern in vim?

Tags: vim

I've got some method calls all over the place in a large file, I'd like to match these lines, select and then yank them as one so I can put them all in a single place.

I can find all the lines I want with `:g/>set` but how do I visually select each line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have multiple visual selections in Vim.

But you can clear a register and append all the matching lines to it:

```
:let @a = ''
:g/>set/y A
```

then create an empty buffer (or navigate to an existing one):

```
:vnew
```

and paste from register `a`:

```
"ap
```

But you probably want something like [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) or [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/).

**edit**

```
:[something]y a
```

means "yank into register `a`".

```
:[something]y A
```

means "append to register `a`".

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: what the capital A stand for there ? Does it means append ? or does it means append to register `a` ? It would work similarly with :g/>set/y B for register b ?

Comment: @XavierT., it means "append to register a" and you are right about `y B`.

Comment: @romainl: I have finally found were it is mentioned in `:help` but it is well hidden. (`:help copy-move` in Vim 7.4 for anyone interested)

Comment: @XavierT. its also explained in `:h quote_alpha`

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is :

1. Remove all the lines without the pattern  `:v/pattern/d`
2. Select the whole new file with `ggyG`
3. Paste somewhere the result with `p`
4. Use undo a few times with `u` to get the file back to its initial state

This is a bit cumbersome, I would welcome a simpler solution.

Comment: How about : 1):v/pattern/d 2):%y 3):tabnew 4)P ? Thus you will have the initial file pristine and untouched, and a file with which you can "mess" around (sort, filter, rename, etc...)

Comment: Come to think of it, there may be another way (YMMV) : simple folding. Please look at my question (SO 18547179) and the very efficient answer given by eleom.